# Array manipulation C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a file with several lines of input, in the form

```
6 7 3 -4 5 6 7 8 * + % ( / ) -
```

where 6 is the number of numbers in the expression, 7 is the number of operands, followed by the actual operands and operators. So far I have the below code, which stores 6 and 7. I am restricted to using `fscanf()`. I must produce output that looks like:

```
3 * -4 + 5 % ( 6 / 7 ) - 8
```

There's a lot more to the project but this is the part where i'm stuck. I have no idea how to print out the statement like that.

I'm also printing the expression to another file, and am restricted to using `fprintf()` for that.

```
while (fscanf (input, "%d %d", &OPN, &OPR)!=EOF);
{
```

Comment: This is conversion of postfix expression into infix expression. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405361/Converting-Postfix-Expressions-to-Infix Above link will give you the idea and the code for conversion.

Comment: @Venkatesh If you look more closely at the question, you will see that this has nothing to do with postfix expressions.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am restricted to using fscanf()*

Homework, right?

You would, I think, be better off reading in a whole line at a time into a line buffer. Use, e.g., `strtok()` to split the string apart wherever a space occurs, and store each return value (a string pointer) in an array of string pointers (e.g., `char *tokens[20];`). If you're going to use the line buffer for something else, you'll have to use `strdup()` to create a copy of each token before storing it in the table, otherwise you'll lose this data.

The simplest way to read in a whole line is by using `fgets()`, but if you must use `fscanf()`, then you could use something like `scanf(" %99[^\n]\n",str);` (replacing `99` with one less than the size of the buffer you are reading the line into).

One last thing:

```
while (fscanf (input, "%d %d", &OPN, &OPR)!=EOF);
{
```

There's a semicolon at the end of the `while()` statement. You'll need to get rid of that.

Comment: With `scanf("%99[^\n]\n",str);`, if the initial `char` in the file is `'\n'`, _nothing_ will be read.  Better to use `scanf(" %99[^\n]",str);`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit to the number of numbers and operators? Then you could use static arrays, otherwise you will have to dynamically allocate arrays of sufficient size.

Basically, you need to store the values in arrays and then process them. Read the operators array to determine if you want to print a number or the operator next. ( `'('` gets printed before, the others after, for example. A `')'` is followed by an operator or the end of the line.)

`fscanf()` moves the file pointer along as it reads, so you can do something like

```
int numnums = 0;
int numops = 0;
int nums[MAXNUMS];
char ops[MAXOPS];

while (fscanf (input, "%d %d", &numnums, &numops)!=EOF)
{
    for(i = 0; i < numnums; ++i)
    {
        fscanf (input, "%d", nums[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < numops; ++i)
    {
        fscanf (input, "%c", nuopsms[i]);
    }

    // use fprintf to print out the ops and nums (and spaces) one at a time.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fi = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int OPN, OPR;

    fscanf(fi, "%d %d", &OPN, &OPR);
    int nums[OPN];
    char ops[OPR];
    int ni, oi;
    for(ni=0; ni < OPN; ++ni)
        fscanf(fi, "%d", &nums[ni]);
    for(oi=0; oi < OPR; ++oi)
        fscanf(fi, " %c", &ops[oi]);
    fclose(fi);

    FILE *fo = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    ni = oi = 0;
    if(ops[0] != '(')
        fprintf(fo, "%d", nums[ni++]);
    while(oi < OPR){
        if(ops[oi] != '(') {
            fprintf(fo, " %c ", ops[oi]);
            if(ops[oi++] == ')' && oi < OPR)
                fprintf(fo, "%c ", ops[oi++]);
        }
        if(oi < OPR && ops[oi] == '(')
            fprintf(fo, "%c ", ops[oi++]);
        if(ni < OPN)
            fprintf(fo, "%d", nums[ni++]);
    }
    fprintf(fo, "\n");
    fclose(fo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This only reads one line of the file. Also, posting a complete answer to a homework question does not help the asker. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for recommendations on how to answer homework questions.

Comment: _This only reads one line of the file._ It is easy to change the loop. s/he does not  asking how to write a loop. I showed the main processing. Whether homework is not a problem, but please do say after you prove it.